# Nextjs Website Componants in not Showing Vercel deployment

Tags: next.js, deployment, web-hosting, vercel

I am creating website on `next.js` and deployed to `vercel`. But after deployment some of my components is not showing. This is website. Here is my 2 website where I facing issue:

```
[Mitnog](https://mitnog.vercel.app/)
[One More](https://restaurent-next.vercel.app
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend checking out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation, especially the part about including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Because with the current state of the question, no one will be able to help you.